# Joomla modules/components overriding

Tags: templates, joomla

I need to ovveride some modules, and I know how to do it http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core
by creating the /html/mod_name/default.php in my template folder.

But how to ovveride only for certain position ?

let assume I need to ovveride the mod_login , that in the "top position" i use the modified mod_login ,then .. how can I have another mod_login in the same page (eg. bottomleft position ) but that use the original mod_login or another mod_login modification, different from the first overriding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
1. Create another file in the same directory called for example default_2.php 
2. Add parameter for the module called "template"(to be show in the admin->extentions->modules->mod_login) 
3. than according to the parameter value(selected in admin for the current instance of module) you need to set template for the module
4. than ou may override these templates according to the http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

I hope it will helpfull.

Comment: I've found out that in joomla >=1.6 there is a method called "layer override", where 
basically you can put more file in the template/html/mod_name/ directory and then 
select in the advanced option of the module the sencond view for the module. But I'll try to do those points to see if 
it works